# NSScrollView scrollToTop

Tags: nsscrollview, scrolltop

Does anyone know the correct way to scroll the NSScrollView to the top?  I was looking for an equivalent to the UIView's scrollToTop method.

This is what I have so far, but its not quite right under all situations

```
[self.contentView scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, MAX(contentView.frameHeight, ((NSView*)self.documentView).frameHeight))];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  Works like a charm!

```
if ([self hasVerticalScroller]) {
    self.verticalScroller.floatValue = 0;
}

NSPoint newOrigin = NSMakePoint(0, NSMaxY(((NSView*)self.documentView).frame) - self.boundsHeight);
[self.contentView scrollToPoint:newOrigin];
```

Answer (score 19):

Updated for **Swift 5**:

If your document view is flipped:

```
scrollView.documentView?.scroll(.zero)
```

otherwise:

```
if let documentView = scrollView.documentView {
        documentView.scroll(NSPoint(x: 0, y: documentView.bounds.size.height))
}
```

Comment: second option works on Catalina 10.15.5 and swift 5.2

Answer (score 6):

This also works fine. Set scroll point of documentView of NSScrollView

```
NSPoint pt = NSMakePoint(0.0, [[self.scrollView documentView]
                               bounds].size.height);
[self.scrollView.documentView scrollPoint:pt];
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous solutions scroll to the bottom when translating to Swift for Mac OS. The y coordinate direction is flipped on Mac OS and iOS.

Swift 3 Solution for Mac OS:

```
scrollView.documentView?.scroll(NSPoint.zero)
```

Comment: Your solution scrolls to the bottom. Maybe you have your view coordinates flipped?

Comment: Ah, clarification. My solution works on Mac OS. The coordinates are flipped on iOS so you'd probably want to use the document bounds height on iOS.