# NSTextView always scrolls to bottom. How do I force it to display at the top?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, nstextview

I have an NSTextView in my XIB UI. In my code, I do

```
[textview insertText:@"text i put here"];
```

many times, and then finally

```
[textview setEditable:NO];
```

BTW, this is to create an information panel for my app.

When I run my app though, the text view always scrolls to the bottom. Is there any way to make it start at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this method

```
[textview scrollToBeginningOfDocument:self];
```

or

//NSTextView inside an NSScrollView you can create object for that scrollview

```
[scrollView.contentView scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, scrollView.documentView.frame.size.height-scrollView.contentSize.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a NSTextView with Interface Builder, it will actually reside inside of NSScrollView. Interface Builder automatically do this.

I mean, this is normal scroll view behavior and you can do 'scroll to top' as usually.

[NSScrollView scrollToTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975434/nsscrollview-scrolltotop)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift one can do

```
textView.scroll(NSPoint.zero)
```

where one loads content